# How do I output the proper coded link with Yahoo Pipes

Tags: rss, pipe, yahoo-pipes

This all seems like it should be working to me but my appended "read more" link displays as plain text instead of as a link... Any insight or help on fixing this would be awesome! My pipe can be found at: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=1a22724d01568b8019be3125c7fb3075

Answer (score 0):

The generated HTML in `description` looks good, however the Yahoo Pipes preview page strips all the HTML formatting, including the `href` you added.

I normally view RSS feeds in [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/). However Google Reader prefers to display the `conetent:encoded` field, which in your example, still contains the full description.

I modified your pipe to copy `description` to `conetent:encoded`:

- http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=eabe80102df76d1aee598648819be4a0

This renders correctly in Google Reader.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Pipes from stripping the html formatting? Solution worked nicely for RSS readers though. Thanks

Comment: I don't think so, but it's the "preview" of the pipe that is not showing the links - they are not actually stripped in the pipe.

Unless you expect people to use the Pipes Preview to view your pipe output, you should be ok.